# Which function resembles this graph?

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematical-astronomy

I am plotting the apparent magnitude of all visible stars sorted from brightest (-1.46) to dimmest (8ish) and this graph is the result. I feel like I've seen this graph's shape before, but I can't remember which function fits it.

[image]

Comment: scaled, translated tangent function

Comment: Inverse of [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)?

Comment: [Probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit) function maybe?